# Deal with null values in reactjs .reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm getting 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of null' when I search an array, not all items in the array have this field, but my code should only look if it's not null, no?

```
checkArray(array) {

    var search = 'Find this';

    var count = array.reduce(function(n, val) {
         return n + (val.outcome_status.category && val.outcome_status.category === search)

    }, 0);

    return count; 
}
```

Comment: it's telling you val.outcome_status is null so add `val.outcome_status && ` to the beginning of your condition

Comment: What this `n + (val.outcome_status.category && val.outcome_status.category === search)` line is basically doing? an number + boolean value. Just interested to know what you are doing there.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it was relying on the fact that a Boolean will get cast to `0` or `1`, so it was basically counting them.

Comment: It's counting the number of times it finds a given string is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not saying that `category` is missing, it's saying that `outcome_status` is null and it's trying to read `category` from a null (which obviously doesn't exist).

The easy way would be to also make sure `val.outcome_status` is a thing:

```
checkArray(array) {

    var search = 'Find this';

    var count = array.reduce(function(n, val) {
         return n + (val.outcome_status && val.outcome_status.category && val.outcome_status.category === search)

    }, 0);

    return count; 
}
```

Looking at your code, it'd probably be cleaner to use `filter()` and then return the length of the remaining:

```
checkArray(array) {
    var search = 'Find this';

    return array.filter(val => val.outcome_status && val.outcome_status.category && val.outcome_status == search).length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add null check for **val.outcome_status** which might also be null, which is giving the exception in this case

To be on the safer side, you can add an **additional null check for val** too

```
checkArray(array) {

    var search = 'Find this';

    var count = array.reduce(function(n, val) {
         return n + (val && val.outcome_status && val.outcome_status.category && val.outcome_status.category === search)

    }, 0);

    return count; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if val.outcome_status is null

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return n + (val.outcome_status && val.outcome_status.category && val.outcome_status.category === search)
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s not a problem of “category”. It shows error because you are trying to access key(category) from nonexsitence key(outcome_status).

So you should check whether key is exist or not

You’d do that by ‘“outcome_status” in val’.
or add outcome_status as a key to all object, and give null value as a initial value.